# How can I edit visual studio's "CurrentSettings.vssettings" to change the current font?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, fonts

I'm attempting to change the current font of visual studio 2015 by editing the .vssettings with a batch script. I'm having a bit of trouble as I can't figure out exactly how the file is set up. When I'm on VS's default font settings the only reference to a font isn't the default font (Consolas), and Changing it to another font name doesn't seem to have an affect. If I change the default font from within VS the font is then listed 5 times in the .vssettings file, because of this I'm unsure of how I would be able to modify it with a script.

How can I go about doing this? Are there any other easier ways to accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of the vssettings file.
2. Make a change to the font
3. Compare the new and the old file.

Then you know what to change. The file is an XML file. So a tool to compare XML files may be helpful here.

Note the vssetting is a privately used file of VS. There is no official documentation. So you might find out the usage with difference checking.